# Ionic app subscribe to event to capture scan

Tags: ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

I have an ionic application that is running on cipher lab scanners. We use it in our warehouse for stock take etc. so we do a lot of barcode scanning.
The developer who I took over from used Mr Ribbons CipherlabRS30CordovaPlugin. With this, we subscribed to a scan event and as soon as a scan was done, we called a callback function and processed it.
We have now upgraded to Cipher Lab RS35 scanners and this code no longer seems to work using this plugin. I would like to switch to a cordova plugin that is not device specific. I cannot figure out with any of the plugins I have found online how to subscribe to a scan event without clicking a button to start scanning etc.
Can anyone help me out with a plugin that could do this kind of thing and some sample code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are several options available:

- [cordova-barcode-scanner](https://github.com/hypery2k/cordova-barcodescanner-plugin) (Deprecated but still usable if stuck on cordova)
- [capacitor-community/barcode-scanner](https://github.com/capacitor-community/barcode-scanner) (Creating the UI can be difficult)
- [capacitor-mlkit-plugin-demo](https://capawesome.io/plugins/mlkit/barcode-scanning/) (New kid on the block that does what the other 2 but better plus more!)

The last one is fairly new and it works great. It even has a multiple scan method!

Comment: Thanks. In all of these, they seem to require a "start scan" action which opens the camera and scans. The devices I'm using are barcode scanners themselves, where a button on the device automatically scans. The software is not required to do the scan. It just needs to pick up when a scan was done independent of it, and then capture it and do some actions. This is what I intended when I mentioned subscribing to the scan event itself, so that I can trigger an action at that point. Hope this is clear. Perhaps I'm just missing something with these other options?

Comment: All plugins require the startscan action. how else would you listen to a scanning event? The scan method needs to run first, if not you cant listen to scanning events. It seems you need to either reevaluate your requirements or need to have native language knowledge to edit the plugin files to customise it to your needs.

Comment: The scan event is triggered by the hardware itself. Barcode scanners have a scanner button that scans automatically. The old plugin I was using worked directly with the hardware to capture that event. I've come to the conclusion though that it's unlikely to find a generic option for this considering that it needs to plug in to a hardware event, and every device is different. I am therefore going a different route altogether, capturing the scan as text input. The plugins you have referenced I will hopefully use in another project I am creating. Thanks for all your help